# Comparison is the thief of joy

Tags: riddle, word

> My prefix can compare;
>   My infix is an implied comparison;
>   Comparators use my suffix;
>   And my whole is comparable to another word of the same length.

What am I?

*The title is a quote commonly attributed to [Theodore Roosevelt](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Theodore_Roosevelt). It is irrelevant to the riddle.*

**Hint 1:**

> I am an eight-letter verb.

**Hint 2:**

> As identified by guesses, the word ends in "-ate"; that's not, however, the suffix referenced in the riddle.

**Hint 3:**

> The prefix is an entity used specifically to compare one "thing" relative to another. The "comparator" referenced in the riddle is the [electronic device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator); however it's a proxy for electronics/digital technology as a whole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Second attempt**

I think the answer is

> Elongate

My prefix can compare;

> **ELO** = a rating system for calculating the relative skill levels of players in zero-sum games such as chess.

My infix is an implied comparison;

> **Long** = there is an implied comparison here to entities which are short (also certain definitions of long can be seen as implied comparisons as there may not be an associated notion of length)

Comparators use my suffix;

> **Gate** = as used by a [Comparator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator)

And my whole is comparable to another word of the same length.

> Lengthen

**Original incorrect answer**

I think you might be

> Macerate

My prefix can compare;

> **Mac** means "son of" in some of the Gaelic languages so it is a familial comparison.
>  Alternatively, [**MAC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_abatement_cost) is an economic cost which compares a company's revenue with and without the impact of reducing environmental negatives.

My infix is an implied comparison;

> **Ace** = a person who excels at a particular sport or other activity. There is an implied comparison with the Ace from a deck of cards (which is a high scoring card in a lot of games).

Comparators use my suffix;

> **Rate**, comparators use statistics (including rates of change) to make comparisons.

And my whole is comparable to another word of the same length.

> Saturate

Hint

> Macerate is an eight-letter verb

Comment: This feels like a streeeeetch.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Only a little on the prefix but everything else seems okay I think.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Definitely a lot less stretchy than some actual correct answers I've seen on recent Riley riddles.

Comment: Creative but not as tight as I think the intended answer is.  Curiously, you got the last few letters correct, though your suffix is not quite it. Everything else is a ways away.

Comment: I especially liked the rot13(znprengr/fnghengr) thing you had going on though.

Comment: @anodyne I've updated my answer to something which seems to fit better.

Answer (score 1):

It could be

> **ANTEDATE**

My prefix can compare;

> **ANT** - insect that can compare items of food and not food?

My infix is an implied comparison;

> **TED** - implied male name as opposed to a female name

Comparators use my suffix;

> **DATE** - comparators probably use the dates to organize the data
>  Props to @hexomino for finding **ATE** (if -ate is what OP meant by "...the last few letters correct" in hexomino's comments)

And my whole is comparable to another word of the same length.

> **ANTEDATE**, very similar to **ANTECEDE**

Title

> TED can be short for Theodore...

Thoughts

> I felt this was far enough away from hexomino's answer to submit.

Comment: We've identified the last few letters it seems. :) Another creative answer but it's not it - I feel the prefix is a bit of a stretch. I'll add another hint in response.